# Increasing PCTFREE on a partitioned table

Tags: oracle, ddl

We have to increase the PCTFREE attribute of a table to check whether it allows 2 transaction can run on the same table and changes the table data without committing the changes. I read it is asktom that increasing PCTFREE can help in removing deadlocks

```
alter table tablename modify default attributes PCTFREE 50;
```

the result displays that the table has been altered but when i checked the dba_tables, it is displaying values for PCTFREE as null. Is there a way to increase the it to a higher value.

Is this a bug that we can't increase the default attributes of a partitioned? table.

Comment: How do you know that PCTFREE is related to the deadlock problem?  Did you look at the deadlock trace file to find the two relevant SQL statements and object IDs?  In my experience deadlocks have always been caused by two SQL statements competing for the same locks in a different order, unindexed foreign keys, or running multiple DMLs against objects with bitmap indexes.  People often wish there is some magic table setting to make deadlocks go away but unfortunately 99+% of all deadlocks are application errors.

Answer (score 1):

For partitioned tables, `dba_tables.pct_free` is always null. The default pctfree is shown in `dba_part_tables.def_pct_free`.

Comment: So is there a way to change the PCTFREE value of a partitioned table? if yes, please let me know how?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand what is `PCTFREE`. In a very simple definition you can define the `PCTFREE` parameter is used to set the percentage of a block to be `reserved` for possible `updates` to rows that already are contained in that block. For example, assume that you specify the following parameter within a `CREATE TABLE` statement:

> PCTFREE 20

This indicates that `20%` of each data block used for this table's data segment will be kept free and available for possible updates to the existing rows already within each block. 
A larger PCTFREE has the following effects:

> •Reserves more room for future updates to existing table rows
>
> •May require more blocks for the same amount of inserted data (inserting
>   fewer rows for each block)

And this is the reason why you found that performce improvement.

Secondly, to increase your PCTFREE you must keep the below point in mind,if you decide not to use the default

> •The sum of PCTFREE and PCTUSED must be equal to or less than 100.
>
> •If the sum equals 100, then Oracle attempts to keep no more than
>   PCTFREE free space, and processing costs are highest.
>
> •The smaller the difference between 100 and the sum of PCTFREE and
>   PCTUSED (as in PCTUSED of 75, PCTFREE of 20), the more efficient space
>   usage is, at some performance cost.

So simply changing PCTFREE 50 will not bring more advantage. Depending on the activity you are trying to perform on database, you must set these values. Read here for different scenarios, what all values you must use. [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96521/schema.htm)

The best way is to drop and create the table with modifed values as:

```
CREATE TABLE  players
        (code  NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY,
         lastname  VARCHAR(20),
         firstname VARCHAR(15),
         position  VARCHAR2(20), 
         team VARCHAR2(20))
      PCTFREE 10   
      PCTUSED 40
      STORAGE 
         (INITIAL 25K
          NEXT 10K
          MAXEXTENTS 10
          MINEXTENTS 3);
```

Comment: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2556828000346627752

Comment: check the link.. . So, if two transactions try to update different rows on the same block - one will have to wait BRIEFLY with a buffer busy wait while the first transaction changes the bits and bytes on the block. It will not have to wait for a commit - it just needs to wait for the first transaction to do its changes and put the modified block back into the cache - then it can make its modifications.

Comment: Perhaps it's worth mentioning that PCTUSED is ignored for locally managed tablespaces with segment space management = AUTO, which is the default (since 10g R2).